# Selenium Grid: chrome driver is not running when using Node machine with different windows login

Tags: selenium-grid

I am using selenium grid for executing test cases in two different systems (Using c#). Thanks to the tutorials online for successful configuration of Hub and the Node.

My application takes the same login as the windows, so the name what we give when we log in to the windows is the same name the application takes. My aim is to test in two different logins. ex: Hub is using LoginA and Node is using LoginB.

Problem: Getting error **"Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService",** when I login to the Node machine with different login as from the Hub.
But if the same login is used in both Hub and Node, not getting any error and the execution continues.

Taken care of below points

1. Installed latest versions of Java, chrome driver
2. Changed environment variable path to point at the chrome driver folder
3. Added "-DWebDriver.chrome.driver" with the chrome driver path in the command running at the Node

**Question: Can we use multiple machines with different logins and work with selenium grid?**

Please help.

Regards,

Rashmi